# Loop over holidays in timeDate package

Tags: r, date, datetime

I would like to extract some holidays using `library(timeDate)`. I have used the following syntax first:

```
EasterSunday<- as.Date(EasterSunday(2015:2018))

EasterSunday
# [1] "2015-04-05" "2016-03-27" "2017-04-16" "2018-04-01"
```

Then I wanted to add the corresponding holiday that date sequence:

```
EasterSunday<- cbind.data.frame(hd=rep('EasterSunday',length(as.Date(EasterSunday(2015:2018)))),date=as.Date(EasterSunday(2015:2018)))

EasterSunday

        #hd            #date

#1 EasterSunday      2015-04-05
#2 EasterSunday      2016-03-27
#3 EasterSunday      2017-04-16
#4 EasterSunday      2018-04-01
```

Then I wanted to loop over all holidays in that package:

```
holidays=c("GoodFriday","EasterSunday","EasterMonday")

# Here I could not find the appropriate function
do.call(cbind, lapply(holidays, function(x) EasterSunday((2015:2018))))

#[,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] ?    ?    ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `match.fun`:

```
library(timeDate)

holidays <- c("GoodFriday", "EasterSunday", "EasterMonday")

do.call(rbind,
        lapply(holidays, function(i){
          foo <- match.fun(i)  
          data.frame(Holiday = i,
                     Dates = as.Date(foo(2015:2018)))

        }))
#         Holiday      Dates
# 1    GoodFriday 2015-04-03
# 2    GoodFriday 2016-03-25
# 3    GoodFriday 2017-04-14
# 4    GoodFriday 2018-03-30
# 5  EasterSunday 2015-04-05
# 6  EasterSunday 2016-03-27
# 7  EasterSunday 2017-04-16
# 8  EasterSunday 2018-04-01
# 9  EasterMonday 2015-04-06
# 10 EasterMonday 2016-03-28
# 11 EasterMonday 2017-04-17
# 12 EasterMonday 2018-04-02
```